# How to combine two tables with the same column and each row there is identity of the table?

Tags: php, sql

How to combine two tables with the same column and each row there is identity of the table? And order by the column

Here's the sample I want:

[image]

what's the sql query snytax

Comment: why are there 2 tables here and not one?

Comment: I had 2 data from a different store

Comment: i dont see why you wouldent put them in one table

Comment: my suggestion would beto create one table and insert all the rows from oth the table.

Comment: but the data from the store are not dozens but thousands and even tens of thousands of data rows
and the data will be updated regularly

I need the results of the query to be able to use in php

Comment: i still dont see why you dont use one table. a single table can easy store many millions of rows

Comment: I get the data from the store on a regular basis
so when there is an update of data from the store "A" I just need to insert a table of the store into my database
and my php pages are automatically updated

and the name of the column of Table 1 and Table 2 different
so i need a sql query to process the data automatically

Comment: it would still be easier with one table, but keep it this way if you want, best of luck.

Comment: ok thanks, but i'm already solved

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Product_id,Product_name,Price,'table1' as table_identity 
    FROM `Table_1`
UNION 
SELECT Product_id,Product_name,Price,'table2' as table_identity 
    FROM `Table_2`
ORDER BY Price ASC
```

This will work if in both tables, the columns have the same data type, and if you make sure to select them in the same order.

Comment: @SetevenWei I'm not, but if my solution solved your problem, remember to select it.

Answer (score 0):

You shold be use "Union All"  join between two tables and add additional column with table name to identity table. you can also make VIEW of this query in SQL Server.

```
select *, 'Table 1' as table_identity  from [table 1]
Union All
select *, 'Table 2' as table_identity from [table 2]
Order by Product_id
```